# Get night mail traffic from Exchange 2019

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a request to retrieve all emails from our Exchange servers sent outside of business hours.
I usually extract using Get-MessageTrackingLog but in this case I need to put a START and an END date.
Not very practical to automate.

So I would like to have a function that generates the night dates from Monday to Friday from 2 months that I would give to Get-MessageTrackingLog
After a lot of research I didn't find anything that does that.
Do you have an idea?
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you work for example 8 hours from 8 am to 4 pm and you want to get the report daily, you could schedule a script that run `Get-MessageTrackingLog` at 8 am as follow

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start ((Get-Date).AddHours(-16)) -EventId RECEIVE -ResultSize Unlimited| Where-Object {$_.Source -eq "STOREDRIVER"}
```